# c# parse/fetch data from html jquery/css-selector like?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, parsing, css-selectors

I am looking for a class or way to parse a string containing a html-document the way I can do it with jquery:

So the main thing I need are css selectors.

I want to get all links, or get all div elements (that are child of a special other element) and things like that.

Are there tools to do these things?